# How to perform join using LINQ for NHibernate

Tags: linq-to-nhibernate

Can i join two tables using  LINQ for NHibernate like I can do in LINQ To SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i got some weird tag for having this question un-answered! so im gonna post an answer myself :) . the thing is LINQ to Nhibernate is not mature enough to handle this. Hopefully it will be available in a next release.

Answer (score 0):

This question was from several years ago.

I just wanted to note for anyone running across it that you can do joins with linq and it works. Also if you set up the relationships in the models you often don't even need to specify the join, nHibernate works it out from the fields you are projecting into the resultset.